# Spring Boot & Security with AngularJS Login page

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm following this tutorial/example of Dave Syer in order to implement a custom AngularJS login page with Spring Security. And the example works fine locally: https://github.com/dsyer/spring-security-angular/tree/master/single

However, when I try to implement this myself, changing some things in a way i would like them to be, I'm not able to authenticate, and I'm not sure where my mistake is. This is the console output where i try to log in:

```
2015-05-04 21:27:18.657 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/**', GET]
2015-05-04 21:27:18.657 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request '/user' matched by universal pattern '/**'
2015-05-04 21:27:18.657 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico']]
2015-05-04 21:27:18.657 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
2015-05-04 21:27:18.657 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true
2015-05-04 21:27:18.657 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@4c1b0a9b, matchingMediaTypes=[application/json], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]]
2015-05-04 21:27:18.658 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : httpRequestMediaTypes=[application/json, text/plain, */*]
2015-05-04 21:27:18.658 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Processing application/json
2015-05-04 21:27:18.658 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : application/json .isCompatibleWith application/json = true
2015-05-04 21:27:18.658 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = false
2015-05-04 21:27:18.658 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Did not match
2015-05-04 21:27:18.658 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Request not saved as configured RequestMatcher did not match
2015-05-04 21:27:18.658 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Calling Authentication entry point.
2015-05-04 21:27:18.658 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2015-05-04 21:27:18.658 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2015-05-04 21:27:18.658 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2015-05-04 21:27:23.106 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/css/**'
2015-05-04 21:27:23.107 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/js/**'
2015-05-04 21:27:23.107 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/images/**'
2015-05-04 21:27:23.107 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
2015-05-04 21:27:23.107 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/error'
2015-05-04 21:27:23.107 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /user at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2015-05-04 21:27:23.107 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /user at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2015-05-04 21:27:23.107 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
2015-05-04 21:27:23.108 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
2015-05-04 21:27:23.108 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /user at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2015-05-04 21:27:23.108 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@248a309c
2015-05-04 21:27:23.108 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /user at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2015-05-04 21:27:23.108 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /user at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2015-05-04 21:27:23.108 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /user' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2015-05-04 21:27:23.108 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /user at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2015-05-04 21:27:23.109 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /user at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2015-05-04 21:27:23.109 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /user at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2015-05-04 21:27:23.109 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2015-05-04 21:27:23.109 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /user at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2015-05-04 21:27:23.109 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.session.SessionManagementFilter  : Requested session ID 5140C94E8B1D8BF835A5A52AAA5F4D5B is invalid.
2015-05-04 21:27:23.109 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /user at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2015-05-04 21:27:23.109 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /user at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2015-05-04 21:27:23.109 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/index.html'
2015-05-04 21:27:23.109 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/home.html'
2015-05-04 21:27:23.109 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/login.html'
2015-05-04 21:27:23.109 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/'
2015-05-04 21:27:23.110 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /user; Attributes: [authenticated]
2015-05-04 21:27:23.110 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2015-05-04 21:27:23.110 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@61c084cb, returned: -1
2015-05-04 21:27:23.110 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2015-05-04 21:27:23.111 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/**', GET]
2015-05-04 21:27:23.111 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request '/user' matched by universal pattern '/**'
2015-05-04 21:27:23.111 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico']]
2015-05-04 21:27:23.111 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
2015-05-04 21:27:23.111 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true
2015-05-04 21:27:23.111 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@4c1b0a9b, matchingMediaTypes=[application/json], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]]
2015-05-04 21:27:23.111 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : httpRequestMediaTypes=[application/json, text/plain, */*]
2015-05-04 21:27:23.111 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Processing application/json
2015-05-04 21:27:23.111 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : application/json .isCompatibleWith application/json = true
2015-05-04 21:27:23.111 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = false
2015-05-04 21:27:23.111 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Did not match
2015-05-04 21:27:23.112 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Request not saved as configured RequestMatcher did not match
2015-05-04 21:27:23.112 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Calling Authentication entry point.
2015-05-04 21:27:23.112 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2015-05-04 21:27:23.112 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2015-05-04 21:27:23.112 DEBUG 1260 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Notable changes (And most likely the source of my issues):

- Credentials are read from MongoDB insteadOf yml file
- Project structure

Since i wanted to use a database instead of property file, i added a user, userRepository, userDetailsService, and changed the security configuration a bit.  Fronted code like Controllers (both from Spring MVC and Angular), .html & .js files are not changed, so i don't think that the problem is in those, nevertheless i paste those lines also:

PS: My test data is populated in db, can be read through JUnit tests with Spring Data like this (so i think that is also not the cause):

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepo;

@Test
public void testUserRepo() {
    User myUser = userRepo.findOneByUsername("myUser");
    assertEquals("myPassword", myUser.getPassword());
    Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = myUser.getAuthorities();
    assertTrue(authorities.contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")));
    assertTrue(authorities.contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER")));
}
```

Relevant Code:

**User.java**

```
@Document(collection = "User")
public class User implements UserDetails {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7206798553934461899L;

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 20)
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max = 8)
    private String password;

    private Set<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();

    @Override
    public Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, Long> {

    User findOneByUsername(String username);

}
```

**UserDetailsService.java**

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsService implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {

         return repository.findOneByUsername(username);
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html", "/login.html", "/").permitAll().anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }
}
```

**HomeController.java**

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public Principal user(Principal user) {
        return user;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/resource")
    public Map<String, Object> home() {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        model.put("id", auth.getName());
        model.put("content", "Hello World");
        return model;
    }
}
```

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**login.html**

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="error">
    There was a problem logging in. Please try again.
</div>
<form role="form" ng-submit="login()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username:</label> <input type="text"
            class="form-control" id="username" name="username" ng-model="credentials.username"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password:</label> <input type="password"
            class="form-control" id="password" name="password" ng-model="credentials.password"/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**hello.js** (AngularJS Controller)

```
angular.module('hello', [ 'ngRoute' ]).config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'home.html',
        controller : 'home'
    }).when('/login', {
        templateUrl : 'login.html',
        controller : 'navigation'
    }).otherwise('/');

    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

}).controller(
        'navigation',

        function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $location, $route) {

            $scope.tab = function(route) {
                return $route.current && route === $route.current.controller;
            };

            var authenticate = function(credentials, callback) {

                var headers = credentials ? {
                    authorization : "Basic "
                            + btoa(credentials.username + ":"
                                    + credentials.password)
                } : {};

                $http.get('user', {
                    headers : headers
                }).success(function(data) {
                    if (data.name) {
                        $rootScope.authenticated = true;
                    } else {
                        $rootScope.authenticated = false;
                    }
                    callback && callback($rootScope.authenticated);
                }).error(function() {
                    $rootScope.authenticated = false;
                    callback && callback(false);
                });

            }

            authenticate();

            $scope.credentials = {};
            $scope.login = function() {
                authenticate($scope.credentials, function(authenticated) {
                    if (authenticated) {
                        console.log("Login succeeded")
                        $location.path("/");
                        $scope.error = false;
                        $rootScope.authenticated = true;
                    } else {
                        console.log("Login failed")
                        $location.path("/login");
                        $scope.error = true;
                        $rootScope.authenticated = false;
                    }
                })
            };

            $scope.logout = function() {
                $http.post('logout', {}).success(function() {
                    $rootScope.authenticated = false;
                    $location.path("/");
                }).error(function(data) {
                    console.log("Logout failed")
                    $rootScope.authenticated = false;
                });
            }

        }).controller('home', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/resource/').success(function(data) {
        $scope.greeting = data;
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed `httpBasic().and()` in `SecurityConfiguration#configure(HttpSecurity)`.

Should be:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().and()authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html", "/login.html", "/").permitAll().anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }
```

Your code is:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html", "/login.html", "/").permitAll().anyRequest()
            .authenticated();
}
```

Best regards, Mark

PS: Keep in mind the user state flags:

```
@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: user state flags are there, i just didnt want to make this post so long..  And about httpBasic.. it was actually there, but i removed that since i have defined my own login page.. As i remember it did not work also with the httpbasic.. I can try again this evening and let you know

Comment: Ok, good. I actually cloned y: dsyer/spring-security-angular and applied your changes step by step. That's the way I discovered the bug.

Comment: Hi @akcasoy have you implemented above use case? also i have same problem, please help me if you have solution which already done it.